# Cannot prevent angular reactive form from submitting

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogInFormSubmit($event)">

      <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">

      <input type="password" formControlName="pwd" placeholder="Password">

      <button
        ion-button
        type="submit"
        color="green"
        class="btn btnAuth"
        >LOG IN</button>

    </form>
```

now i want when i press the submit button to check if my form is valid and if is not to prevent from submitting.

I already tried inside `onLogInFormSubmit($event)` to `return false` and `preventDefault()` on the event but neither did the job.

Is it so hard to just prevent a submit action or am i missing something?

PS. my form is properly initialized at my .ts file.

Comment: What does your component code look like? Did you set up validators on your form group when setting it up?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes as i wrote my form is properly initialized. I didnt post that code beacause i think is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to disable the submit button whilst the form is invalid:

```
<button ion-button
    type="submit"
    color="green"
    class="btn btnAuth"
    [disabled]="!nameOfFormObject.valid">LOG IN</button>
```

Check out the [NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) object.

[Example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjq9hj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Isn't `[disabled]` a `templateDriven` feature? and we shouldn't mix reactive with template driven?

Comment: @AshishRanjan Well they do a similar thing in the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for reactive forms: `<button type="submit"
            [disabled]="heroForm.pristine" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>`. I was under the impression that you shouldn't mix the input elements / generation stuff, but the buttons are exempt.

Comment: Yeah, they have it in the docs. I guess buttons are exempted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes i understand that approach but what i want is when the user click the button and the form is invalid to display the errors for every control